# What clear product for sealing an exterior stained door

Tags: staining, finishing, wood-finishing, varnishing

I have a light-colored oak exterior door which I have stained. I have realized I need to seal it somehow.

In reading what would make sense for sealing a stained exterior door, I came across [marine spar varnish](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Duralux-Marine-Paint-1-qt-Clear-Spar-Varnish-M738-4/205127238?cm_mmc=ecc-_-THD_ORDER_CONFIRMATION_BOSS_STH-_-V1_M1_CA-_-Product_URL&ecc_ord=WP32659366&em_id=842aa133e52b32a7ed851a964954e5aec004ce49904aa66cff9dc2c39f29203b) as what seemed like the preferred solution. This included it being preferred over polyurethane, which I read could crack under significant UV.

However, in the couple videos I have seen of spar varnish, it seems to significantly shift the color. While the one I bought is labeled "clear", I have my concerns.

Should I expect "clear" marine spar varnish to significantly shift the underlying color of the wood? If it is likely to shift the color, is there a better alternative I should consider?

Comment: First see what the stain instructions recommend.  Different sealer formulations might not work well with your stain.

Comment: Try it on a separate piece of material that you have stained or test it on an inconspicuous part of the door to determine how it will affect the appearance.

Answer (score 0):

All wood is natural and every piece is different. You'll get different results on *your* pieces of "light colored oak" than I will on mine. The only way to know for sure is to test the finish on *your* wood.

That said, you will probably want a "water white" finish. It's designed to be non-yellowing when it dries, so it should have the minimum impact on your wood's color. I don't know if spar varnish is made in water white or not, but it's worth a look.

Also, not too many people actually protect their doors with spar varnish. Paint or stain with lacquer, varnish, or polyurethane are the normal treatments. That's not to say you can't/shouldn't use a spar varnish, but it's probably not necessary unless your door is directly exposed to the weather (no storm door, no overhang, facing into the prevailing winds).